# In eclipse RCP Application in which file the initial perspective starts loading and ends?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

In my RCP application I just want to know in which file the initial perspective starts loading and ends. Initial perspective loading is related to my application or is it related to eclipse?

Comment: What do you mean by 'which file'? Are you asking about the Eclipse source code? Perspective loading is a very complex operation.

Comment: I want to test the efficiency of my code, So I need to measure the time takes to load initial perspective. So I want to know in which place I need to add my timer ?

Comment: Well you can't change the Eclipse source code so you can only put timers in your code. Unless you have a specific problem with the perspective loading this is not likely to be a useful thing to try and time.

Comment: My application having 5 perspectives, So how these perspectives will load. all at a time or initial perspective will load once and other perspectives will load separately?

Comment: A 'perspective descriptor' is created for all perspectives, but this is a very lightweight object. Only the parts associated with the current perspective are loaded during startup.

Comment: Is there any listener for perspective loading ? (like IExecutionListener for ResetPerspective).